# How to add an image to a button dynamically when i press the button android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
case R.id.btn_sound:
        if (sp.getBoolean("mute", false)) {
            ed.putBoolean("mute", false);
            mp.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sound)).setText(getString(R.string.btn_mute));
        } else {
            ed.putBoolean("mute", true);
            mp.setVolume(0, 0);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sound)).setText(getString(R.string.btn_sound));
        }
        ed.commit();
break;
```

Instead of text

> setText(getString(R.string.btn_sound))

I want to show image when I click on a button

Comment: Make an image act like a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use button and set your image as backgroundResource with this method : `Button.setBackgroundResource(yourResID)`
2. Use ImageButton and set your image as ImageResource with this method :
   `ImageButton.setImageResource(yourResID)`

Note : Even you can use right or left drawable for your button beside your text if you want keep both text and image in your button.

Answer (score 1):

Just try setBackground() method. Or use ImageButton and then you can use setImageResource() method.